# Filtering my postgreSQL table by category

Tags: php, postgresql

**Question**

I am wondering how I would implement a filter into my table, i want to filter by category. Is there an easy way to do this? Iwas wondering earlier whether using SQL commands would work, for example if i wanted to select fruit:

```
SELECT Foodtype, Manufacturer, Description, Price FROM food
    WHERE Category = Fruit;
```

Would this work or is this not the correct way to do this?

**Code**

The table:

```
<?php
    $conn = pg_connect("host=db.dcs.aber.ac.uk port=5432
                                    dbname=teaching user=csguest password=********");
    $res  = pg_query($conn, "SELECT Foodtype, Manufacturer, Description, Price FROM food
    ORDER BY Category ASC");
        echo "<table id=\"myTable\" border='1'>";
        while ($a = pg_fetch_row($res)) {
            echo "<tr>";
            for ($j = 0; $j < pg_num_fields($res); $j++) {
            echo "<td>" . $a[$j] . "</td>";
            }
            echo "<td><form id='cart' name='cart' method='POST' action='addToBasket.php'>
            <input type='submit' name='Select' id='Select' value='Add To Basket'>
            </form></td>";
            echo "</tr>\n";
            }
        echo "</table>\n";
?>
```

The filter:

```
<select name="category" id="category">
    <option value="Alcoholic">Alcohol</option>
    <option value="Canned">Canned Food</option>
    <option value="Dairy">Dairy</option>
    <option value="Dessert">Dessert</option>
    <option value="Frozen">Frozen Food</option>
    <option value="Fruit">Fruit</option>
    <option value="Junk Food">Junk Food</option>  
</select> 
<input  type="submit" name="submit" value="Search"/>
```

Comment: This is correct. You can use that.

Comment: Where exactly would that code go, could I place it inside the <select> part, or does it go where the table code is?

Comment: @ogres Do you know if that will work?^ Are you talking about the SQL commands RushFan2112?

Comment: Yes, the SQL, not sure where it goes

Comment: @ogres I have tried this : $Alcoholic = pg_query("SELECT Foodtype, Manufacturer, Description, Price FROM food WHERE Category = Alcoholic"); But it is not working, I have placed this under the table code.